# Help! Верстка на flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Нужно сверстать вот такой блок на flex.

Идея в том, что под основным контейнером с контентом должен быть активный градиентный блок, "толкающий" основной контент вправо (при наведении внутри него будут появляться иконки навигации).

Это блок, вроде бы, сверстать получилось, а вот с колонками проблема.

Нужен взгляд и помощь опытных коллег по цеху.

```css
.ui-h-tile {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  min-height: calc(100vh / 4);
}

.ui-h-tile-v-tools-box {
  background: rgba(182, 125, 118, 1.0);
  min-height: calc(100vh / 4);
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.ui-h-tile-content {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 7px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: baseline;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.ui-h-tile-img {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  background: #cccccc;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: calc(100vh / 4);
}

.ui-h-tile-content-title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.ui-h-tile-text-name {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #111111;
}

.ui-h-tile-text-label {
  align-content: end;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-h-tile">
  <div class="ui-h-tile-v-tools-box">
  </div>
  <div class="ui-h-tile-content">
    <div class="ui-h-tile-img">
      <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-h-tile-content-title">
      <div class="ui-h-tile-text-name">text</div>
      <div class="ui-h-tile-text-label">text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: пытаюсь сверстать такой tile]

За любую помощь и подсказки спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так вроде бы... **в три флекс контейнера**

flex1 и flex2 надо объеденить но я оставил специально *что бы было видно суть*

```css
img{
  display:block;
  width:180px;
}
.flex{
  display:flex;
}
.block{
  width:180px;
}
.block1{
  width:calc(100% - 180px);
}
.flex1{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.flex2{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  
}
.flex,.flex1,.flex2{
  align-items:center;
}
.grad{
  width:10px;
  background:linear-gradient(to left,red,gold);
  height:200px;
  border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;
}
   .flex2 div p:first-child{
  font-size:1.6em
}
```

```html
<div class="flex"> 
  <div class="grad"></div>
 <div class="block">
   <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-bunker/50064/5a071b8f0989db20d4b59d3676e34399b30c2b9c/orig" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="block1">
   <div class="flex1">
     <p>Имя Фамилия</p>
     <p>Активность:<span>12.02.2018</span> &nbsp; <span>22:01</span> </p>
   </div>
   <div class="flex2"> 
     <div> 
       <p>текст</p>
       <p>пояснение</p>
     </div>
    <div> 
       <p>текст</p>
       <p>пояснение</p>
     </div>
    <div> 
       <p>текст</p>
       <p>пояснение</p>
     </div>
    <div> 
       <p>текст</p>
       <p>пояснение</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: не стал ваши class лопатить .. так как не люблю такие именования ...

Comment: Зато всякие `block1` и `flex2` оооочень информативны))